# Range in Array Java

Tags: java, arrays, range

I need to complete this task. But I am not entirely sure how to get the range into the array. I think I am supposed to use a loop somehow but I do not get it to work.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
public class A2_1 
{
    static Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) 

    {
        int [] myArray = new int [1000000];     
        int x;

    for ( x = 0; x <= 100; x++)
    {  
        myArray [x] = x+1;
    }
    System.out.println(myArray);
    }
}
```

This is the task:

"Create a program that generates 1,000,000 integer random values in the range of [1,..,100] and for any given x (between 1 and 100) taken from the user input computes "(     ℎ    )/1,000,000".
This value must be comparable to the CDF of a uniform distribution U[1,100] at point x."

Comment: Use a Java random number generator: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Comment: (Math.random()*100) +1

Comment: Please indent your code sensibly before you ask people to read it.

Comment: I guess this probably means you need an int array of size 100, create a million random numbers and use those to index the array and increment the corresponding element.

Comment: Some hints how you could solve your problem: create a for loop that loops 1000000 times and fills the array with random numbers from 1-100. (see Dawnkeepers advice for example). Second read in x with your scanner. 3rd loop over your array comparing the stored random number to x and keep count. 4th print the required result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im not going to give you the answer since this sounds like homework but I will help you break it down into manageable chunks.

First, generate 1000000 random numbers between 1 and 100. You were on the right track and combine it with Dawnkeepers hint. `int[] randoms = new int[1000000];` is an int array with a size of 1000000. Now iterate over each index and assign it a random number(see above). Now you have an array with a million random numbers. Generating a million randoms can be a lengthy procedure depending on you machine, so yea.

Next, use the Scanner class to get the users input.(pro tip: dont use the same variable name for your scanner as your variable in the for loop lol). Now do an if check to make sure they enter a number between 1 and 100. `if(val > 0 && val <= 100)`. If this passes, move on, else quit or prompt for user to give a new input. Using the scanner is pretty trivial so I wont go into this.

Finally, iterate through your list of randoms and keep a counter of how many numbers less then or equal to `x`.

```
int counter = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < randoms.length; i++) {
  //if randoms[i] is less then or equal x, counter++
}
```

Take that counter and do your math, `int final_answer = counter/randoms.length;`

That's all that is to it. There are more efficient ways of doing this but I tried to make it simple to follow. If I misread the question, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This really helped.